# Mechanism to talk to moderator who deleted an answer

Tags: discussion, feature-request

An answer of mine was deleted by a moderator. I'm not going to link which answer, since I don't want this to be interpreted as a request to undelete it.

However the moderator left no comment, nor flagged it in any way. I want to gain some useful knowledge from this experience, but without knowing why it was deleted, or having anyway to communicate with the moderator this is very difficult.

It would be useful if the comments system on deleted posts would continue functioning, but only to talk to people who flagged or deleted the post.

Comment: Why not simply provede the answer text as a quote in this question? Otherwise it's rather hard to say.

Comment: @RobertLongson Because I want to avoid this becomming a discussion on this specific answer, and more a general point about my feeling of frustration at seeing my answer deleted, and having no idea why or how to find out why, and how we can avoid this in the future.

Comment: Your frustration will not be less after you talked with the mod.

Comment: Can confirm, @rene. People usually get more frustrated after talking to me.

Answer (score 8):

Use Meta. That's one of the purposes of this platform: to ask for support in using the site, including to question the decision made by a moderator.

Plead your case in a Meta question, including both the text of your original post and your argument(s) for why you think it should not have been deleted. The community will weigh in, both with votes on your question and with answers either supporting or disagreeing with you. If it is determined that the deletion was in error or otherwise not in best interest of the site, either the moderator who made the original decision or another one of us will undelete the post.

Answers that have been deleted already contain an explanation, in the form of a link to [this page from the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers), which contains a list of reasons why answers may be deleted. Chances are very good that your answer was deleted for one of those reasons.

It simply doesn't scale for moderators to leave personalized comments on every answer that they delete. This past week alone, diamond moderators on Stack Overflow deleted around 2,000 posts. Even if it took us only 30 seconds to leave a comment on each of those posts, that would add up to an unreasonable chunk of time, especially since, in most cases, it is obvious why the post was deleted.

---

In this specific case, your most recent answer was deleted by a moderator because it did not appear to be providing an answer to the question. It was flagged by a community member as "not an answer", and the diamond moderator who reviewed that flag agreed with it. I'm betting that the reason your answer was interpreted this way was because it ended with the sentence, "I don't know why this is." That's usually a strong signal that someone is trying to add more information to their question (which should be done as an edit, rather than as an answer).

Comment: Probably the reasons are often the same. Some kind of list to choose from plus a custom field similarly to the close votes procedure could probably decrease the needed times quite a lot. Would still mean more time but considerably less of it and the additional ability to have statistics.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @cody. How many moderators are there that deleted those 2000 posts? i.e. how many posts are deleted per moderator?

Comment: @YairHalberstadt There are [21 moderators](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) so just divide by that.

Comment: @Yair It varies from day to day. Moderating Stack Overflow isn't our full-time job, so we handle flags when we have a chance.

Comment: Just for the sake of no one else doing this math, 30 seconds for each (2,000) posts is about 16 hours of writing comments per week, with 21 moderators equals almost 50 minutes per week per moderator. I wonder how much time is taken responding to questions about post deletions on Meta - my guess is not 16 hours a week.